# How to check if user logged and then redirect?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have tried all answers I could find, this is my routing:

```
const loggedIn = !!localStorage.getItem('token');

const Routes = () => (
    <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
                !loggedIn ? (
                    <Redirect to="/login" />

                ) : (
                    <Redirect to="/welcome" />
                )
            )}/>
</Switch>
    </div>
);

export default Routes;
```

However, it is still not working.. I am getting an error on other container:

> menuContainer.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of
>   null

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userId: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('logged')).id,
            loginRole: localStorage.getItem('loggedRole')
        }
    };
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

EDIT: I don't have any id if user is not logged in. That's the whole point. :) If user is not logged in, it should redirect back to /login.

Comment: can u tell us whats in your localStorage ?

Comment: Sure, when user is logged there is an id of logged user, when not, there is no key.

Comment: try `console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('logged')))` and check whether it is returning null ?

Comment: `Routes.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null`

Comment: By default, if the item you are accessing does not exist, it returns `null`. If I do `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('hello'))` it will return `null`. So where and when are you storing the item `token`?

Comment: So what is the solution? It is stored when user is logged in

Comment: First of all, did u `setItem` before getting? `localStorage.setItem('logged',someuserobj)`,

Comment: @strongtu where are you doing `localStorage.setItem('token', 'value')` ?

Comment: Same question for loggedRole, logged and token

Comment: create `var userobj = { id : 12 }` and then `localStorage.setItem('logged', JSON.parse(userobj))` then try getting it.

Comment: I didn't `setItem` this is retrieved via API. it is `set` when token is received.

Comment: `.id` is retrieved when user is logged only

Comment: what does the `token` contain??

Comment: it is JWT, so encoded string.

Comment: @VíñịtVịłłă, logging in works fine if user is found, what doesn't work is the redirection to /login if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to set item in localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('name', value )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how do u set the localStorage object before.

`var userobj = { id : 12 }`

`localStorage.setItem('logged',JSON.stringify(userobj))`

then try getting it like `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('logged')).id; //return 12`

This is how it needs to be done. If the `token` which u receive has the id, u have to manually set it before getting it :)

Comment: But I don't have any `id` if user is not logged in. That's the whole point. :) If user is not logged in, it should redirect back to `/login`.